# oracle row level lock in a seesion, does not raise error to other sessions

Tags: oracle, concurrency, locking

I have this query in session 1 :
   **select * from x where x.id = 625 for update nowait ;**
and I have another query in session 2 :
     **update x set x.code = 0 where id = 625 ;** 
I don't want session 2 waiting for session 1 to commit or rollback.
I want to raise error to session 2 until session 1 not commited.
my problem is session 2 waits for session 1 to release resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In session 2 you need to issue another `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` to obtain a lock on the record, and then do the update in the same transaction.
The `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement must use the same `WHERE` conditions as `UPDATE` in order to lock the same record(s) you are going to update.

If the record is already locked, then the first `SELECT FOR UPDATE` throws :
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

```
SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE id = 625 FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
update x set x.code = 0 where id = 625 ;
```

Comment: dear krokodilko, thank you for your answer, but is there any other solution available for this problem? because in your solution, I should change several places in my code project and add "SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT" before update or deletes!

Comment: If you want to throw the exception when the record is locked, then no - there is no other solution. `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` is the only command in Oracle I know that is able to throw the error in such a case, all other DML commands (update, delete, and insert sometimes also) wait unitil the lock will be released, this is a standard SQL behaviour.

Comment: for example I want to protect a record from delete, while this record is locked in another transaction. I don`t want delete query wait until record  to be unlocked and then delete record.